# Get price value from a string

Tags: regex, string, currency, yahoo-pipes

I have a string, where price value($544.50) can be anywhere in the string.
eg: HP G60-630US Notebook: Laptops | RadioShack.com --> $259.97 (radioshack.com)

I need to get the value: 259.97 out of the string

For this i tried using some random regex's.
But no luck!

Can someone help me, giving a proper regex string for retrieving this price value from a string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it always in dollars ($) ?

Comment: Simple regex: `\$\d+(\.\d{1,2})?`

Comment: \$\d+(\.\d{1,2})? This works! any idea about yahoo pipes. After matching the number, we need to get only that number. For that we need to give a value in the value field. any idea?

Answer (score 13):

This regex will work with multiple currencies: $ £ €

```
[\$\£\€](\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)
```

[Example](https://xrg.es/#1cz94ew)

Comment: [\$\£\€](\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)
Its working! One more lame question. In Yahoo pipes, using regex module, after matching we need to give a value in the value field. So that i can only get the number out of the complete string. Can u help ?

Comment: The number is in the first match of the regex. Usually match[0] is the complete string and match[1] is the number you are looking for. I don't know about yahoo pipes. but can you choose the match you want to use?

Answer (score 1):

`[$]?[0-9]*(\.)?[0-9]?[0-9]?`

This should match those with a `$` sign and those without.

Comment: That finds the "60" and "630" in the model number also.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will probably work:

```
/\$(\d*\.?\d+?)/
```

Answer (score 0):

\$(\d*\.?\d*) should work, not optimal but probably useful.

(Important: escape $ and ., which are special characters)

Comment: This will match something like this too: `$300 rfersijfurhfurnfuerfnurjfrifnrunfurfrfurhufrhfhr 4594545`

Comment: @micha: I forgot to escape the ., yes. But even without that I don't see how your string would match? d matches a digit, . anything (but once maximum). I used * instead of + to allow for prices such as $.50

Answer (score 0):

This one finds first decimal number in a string:

```
^[^\d]*(\d+|\d+((,|\.)\d{1,2}))(\s|[a-zA-Z)]|€|$).*
```

- looks only for numbers with 0-2 decimals decimal point or comma allowed
- no need for spaces before or after the number
- number must not end with any delimiter (eg. 12.12. or 12! is not returned)
- number can end with Euro sign €
- works on US negative numbers ($1233.50)

Comment: When I test that, on the given radio shack string, it finds no match.

Comment: It should work on positive numbers eg. $1233.50. Have now updated th regex to accept also negative numbers: ($1233.50)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to replace and extract

**Extract:**

```
preg_match('/\$([0-9]+[\.]*[0-9]*)/',$string,$matches);
foreach($matches as $match) {
  echo $match."<br>";
}
//echo $matches[0]; for just the first match
```

**Modify/Replace:**

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/\$([0-9]+[\.]*[0-9]*)/', function ($matches) {


            foreach ($matches as $match) {
                // only if value is !empty and higher than 0
                $tmp = str_replace("$", "", $match);
                if ($tmp > 0 && $tmp != "") {
                    //do something to $tmp in this case round to two decimal places
                    return "$" . round($tmp,2);

                }

            }

        }, $string);
```

There's probably a better way to handle the symbol on my replacement example.

Answer (score 0):

Regex to filter out number:
String regex = ([0-9]+[, .]?)+
You can use it like this:

CurrencySymbol + regex
regex + CurrencySymbol